# improve preg / pcre / regex to find PHP variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

String to parse:

```
$str = "
public   $xxxx123;
private  $_priv   ;
         $xxx     = 'test';
private  $arr_123 = array();
"; //    |       |
   //     ^^^^^^^---- get the variable name
```

**What I got** so far:

```
    $str = preg_match_all('/\$\S+(;|[[:space:]])/', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $match = str_replace('$', '', $match);
        $match = str_replace(';', '', $match);
     }
```

It works but I want to know **if I can improve the preg**, e.g. get rid of the two `str_replace` and maybe include `\t` in `(;|[[:space:]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a positive lookbehind, you can get *only* that what you need, to be sure you'll only match *valid* variable names, I've used this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\$)[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/',$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

which correctly shows:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'xxxx123',
    1 => '_priv',
    2 => 'xxx',
    3 => 'arr_123'
  )
)
```

Which is all you need, no memory waisted on an array containing all variables with their leading and/or trailing chars.

The expression:

- `(?<=\$)` is a positive lookbehind
- `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`: is the regex PHP's site suggests themselves [on their document pages](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: this would also match other random strings like $("=§/&="§/$. also it would not properly match something like $x=123;

Comment: still would match for example in here "!"§$%&/()=?`" -> $%&/()

Comment: @andreasLinden: I've edited my answer, to now use the regex PHP recommend themselves to match only valid variable names

Comment: okay fine, what is missing now to have a perfect solution: exclude variables inside of single quoted strings :D

Comment: Several good answers, including yours Andreas, I chose this to be the best fitting answer, thank you both

Comment: @AndreasLinden: That'll be a bit tricky, since lookarounds have to be of fixed lengths, but then again, you could just `preg_replace('/(?<=\')(.*)\$/', '$1', $str);` to remove all `$` from single quoted strings

Answer (score 1):

simply use backreferences

```
preg_match_all('/\$(\S+?)[;\s=]/', $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {

     // $match is now only the name of the variable without $ and ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the regex a little bit, take a look:

```
$str = '
public   $xxxx123;
private  $_priv   ;
         $xxx     = "test";
private  $arr_123 = array();
';

$matches = array();

//$str = preg_match_all('/\$(\S+)[; ]/', $str, $matches);
$str = preg_match_all('/\$(\S+?)(?:[=;]|\s+)/', $str, $matches); //credits for mr. @booobs for this regex

print_r($matches);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $xxxx123;
            [1] => $_priv 
            [2] => $xxx 
            [3] => $arr_123 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxxx123
            [1] => _priv
            [2] => xxx
            [3] => arr_123
        )

)
```

Now you can use the `$matches[1]` in the foreach loop.

::Update::

After using regex "/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/" the output looks correct.

String:

```
$str = '
public   $xxxx123; $input1;$input3
private  $_priv   ;
         $xxx     = "test";
private  $arr_123 = array();
```

';

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $xxxx123
            [1] => $input1
            [2] => $input3
            [3] => $_priv
            [4] => $xxx
            [5] => $arr_123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxxx123
            [1] => input1
            [2] => input3
            [3] => _priv
            [4] => xxx
            [5] => arr_123
        )

)
```

Comment: I'd change the regex even more so that it matches even if there's no space before assignation operator: `\$(\S+?)(?:[=;]|\s+)`

Comment: problem here: `$input; $input2;` it does not match `$input2;`

Comment: @sbooob Nice one, I'll change the regex.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't have that problem? What string are you using?

Comment: This simple one seems to work: `/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/`. "Simple" as it is just the regex for a valid PHP var name according to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)